Can I keep my thumb on the B♭ Briccialdi key?
A couple of elementary flute books lead me to believe that the standard fingering for the note B♭ on the flute is:



Note
Thumb
Left Hand
Right Hand
Little Finger




B♭(i)
B♮
1 – –
1 – –
D♯



It follows directly that the standard fingering for an F major scale is:



Note
Thumb
Left Hand
Right Hand
Little Finger




F
B♮
1 2 3
1 – –
D♯


G
B♮
1 2 3
– – –
D♯


A
B♮
1 2 –
– – –
D♯


B♭(i)
B♮
1 – –
1 – –
D♯


C
–
1 – –
– – –
D♯


D
B♮
– 2 3
1 2 3
–


E
B♮
1 2 3
1 2 –
D♯


F
B♮
1 2 3
1 – –
D♯




Most simple fingering charts (from a variety of sources) show a single fingering for each note in the gamut, but with an exception — A♯/B♭ is often given two configurations: (i) as above, and (ii) as below:



Note
Thumb
Left Hand
Right Hand
Little Finger




B♭(ii)
B♭
1 – –
– – –
D♯



This places the thumb on the B♭ thumb lever (the Briccialdi key), rather than its usual place, the B♮ thumb lever.
As far as I can tell, which lever the thumb is on will only determine whether the “B” is a B♮ or a B♭; none of the other notes in a diatonic scale will be affected.
So, if I’m playing in a key/scale with flats, should I just keep my left-hand thumb on the B♭ Briccialdi key?
For example, rather than the table above, would it be good practice to play an F major scale as follows?:



Note
Thumb
Left Hand
Right Hand
Little Finger




F
B♭
1 2 3
1 – –
D♯


G
B♭
1 2 3
– – –
D♯


A
B♭
1 2 –
– – –
D♯


B♭(ii)
B♭
1 – –
– – –
D♯


C
–
1 – –
– – –
D♯


D
B♭
– 2 3
1 2 3
–


E
B♭
1 2 3
1 2 –
D♯


F
B♭
1 2 3
1 – –
D♯



The book Essential Elements 2000 — Comprehensive Band Method — Flute book 1 teaches the keys: F major, B♭ major, E♭ major, and A♭ major; there are no B♮’s, so I can probably use the Briccialdi key as a default thumb position for the entire book, right? It seems odd that it gives fingering (i) for B♭ and barely mentions the Briccialdi key’s existence.

TL;DR Yes, it is very advisable to keep your thumb on the thumb B♭ key when it is appropriate, but make sure you are able to use the "regular" fingering as well.
Personally, I leave my thumb on the thumb B♭ key very often when I'm playing in passages without any B♮4 and B♮5. (Sometimes, I even leave my thumb on the thumb B♭ key even when there are B♮4 or B♮5, and slide my thumb to switch between the notes!) My advice is to get used to using thumb B♭.
The only other note this affects is F♯6. You must use the regular thumb key (B♮ lever) for that note, instead of thumb B♭ (try it for yourself to hear the difference).
If you observe the flute mechanism, you'll see that the B♭ trill key (the lever you press with your right index finger) does the exact same thing as the thumb B♭ key! With the B♮ key depressed, try comparing the action of adding thumb B♭ vs. adding B♭ trill. You'll find they are the exact same. Since the B♭ trill key is automatically depressed for notes like A5, this makes it very convenient to use for chromatic runs including both B♭ and B♮ in the first two registers.
The best practice is to use either the thumb B♭ or the trill B♭ fingerings (bottom two fingerings in the below diagram), since they have better intonation than the "regular" fingering. This is a very minor difference on C flute, but it can be quite significant on piccolo.

(The diagram is from the excellent Woodwind Fingering Guide, which is always my go-to resource for finding trill, tremolo, and alternate fingerings.)

The "default" position for the left thumb is on the B-natural key, but in an extended passage that only uses B-flats it can be advantageous to leave the thumb on the B-flat key.
For the example from the question (an F-major scale): if you see the B-flat coming up, it would make sense to start with the thumb on B-flat. After taking the thumb off for C you'd probably replace it on the B-natural for D unless there are more B-flats coming up.
Particularly in technically difficult passages it's good practice to only move fingers when they need to move. This applies to any woodwind instrument.

As long as there are no B♮4, B♮5, or F♯6 coming up, I'd just leave my thumb on the thumb B♭ key. After all, that results in minimal finger movement :)
